# Minimum space dimension to place n-points knowing pairwise distances

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, dimension-theory

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ points.
Assuming I know the pairwise distances for each pair of points.
What would be the minimum dimension of the space in which I could place those $n$ points with respect to the different pairwise distances.

The idea would be to set a first point at random coordinates in a multi-dimensional space.
Then, add the other $n-1$ points so that the pairwise distances are respected.

Sorry, it's maybe a trivial question for mathematicians but I'm still wondering if the  relation: "number of points $\to$ minimum dimension of space" does exist.

Comment: The Schoenberg criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix) is relevant. It's a criterion for which a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^k$ can realize a given set of pairwise distances.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the basic result, start with

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma)

or Google "Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma".

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the lead.
It seems to quite fit what I had in Mind.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose your $\binom{n}{2}$ distances are all exactly 1.  Then they determine an $(n{-}1)$-simplex
in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and those distances cannot be realized in a lower dimension.
For example, three points at unit distance determine an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$;
four points at unit distance determine a regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, whose six edge
lengths are each 1.

            [image: tetrahedron]

Generally, the more interesting question is how to embed the distances in a space
of modest dimension without significant distortion.
See, e.g., the chapter by Indyk and Matoušek,
"Low-distortion embeddings of finite metric spaces,"
*[Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395)*, 2018, or
the 2006 paper by Bartal, "[Embedding finite metric spaces in low dimension](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.132.7214)."

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, for some special distances, you can embed the points in a fewer-dimensional space. If this is important, one way to count the correct dimension would be the rank of a certain matrix.

$(b-a,c-a)=(d(a,b)^2+d(a,c)^2-d(b,c)^2)/2$

If you fix a point $a$ and place the other values of this dot product into an $n-1$ by $n-1$ symmetric matrix, the rank of that matrix will be the dimension of the space you can embed the points in.